# Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04 64b, No import button on Certificate Servers

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, firefox, certificates

I am on Xubuntu 16.04 64bits, I have no import button on Firefox

Firefox > 3 lines icon > Preferences > Advanced > tab Certificates > View Certificates > tab Servers -> there is no "Import..." button, and it should be one.

I am installing on Firefox the 2 certificates used in Spain to deal with the government. [This video](https://youtu.be/uePxWRjCY_o?t=323) on 5:23 shows how the Servers tab has an "Import..." button.

The procedure the video follows is this:

- First they import an authority certificate in the Authorities tab, there is Import button.
- Then the video installs the servers certificate, in the video there is "Import..." button there, but **not** on any of my 3 computers running Xubuntu 16.04 64bits fully updated.

Do anyone knows what could be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Alternatively, do anyone know how to install a server certificate on Firefox in Ubuntu? The certificate is a .cer file format.

Comment: I have tried this: launching Firefox with "sudo firefox" and the same still happens, no Import button on Certificate Manger > tab Servers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution to this problem is that Firefox does not allow anymore to import server certificates, it does it by its own, online, Firefox has his own method to check the validity and veracity of a server.

Anyway, I achieved getting my card reader working and the certificates being accepted just by installing the Authority certificate, no need to install a server certificate. Possibly what was needed was a Firefox restart or possibly a computer restart.